# unpack requires a string argument of length 43 - Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have the following function, that reads from a `UDP` socket, and appends to a string `data`:

```
DATA_SIZE = 2048 
def handle_read(self):
        """
        This handles the incoming ntp response
        """
        try:
            data = ""
            while 1:
                current_data, _ = self.recvfrom(self.DATA_SIZE)
                self.log.info("msg: %s" % current_data)
                (header, length, typeID, param1, param2,
                param3, param4, name_string, checksum, footer,
                ) = struct.unpack("!2B I 4H 24s I B", current_data)
                print  (header, length, typeID, param1, param2,
                param3, param4, name_string, checksum, footer,
                )
                if not current_data:
                    break
                data += current_data
            self.log.info(data)
            # parse with the pysnmp into a summary
        except Exception, e:
            self.log.exception("The following exception happened: %s" % e)
        finally:
            self.handle_close()
```

when I execute the code I get:

```
  File "hello.py", line 67, in handle_read
    ) = struct.unpack("!2B I 4H 24s I B", current_data)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 43
```

I've tried to adjust the string argument size, but with the same error. The function basically has to do is to read from `self.recvfrom()` and append to the `data`. Could someone help?
The structure of `self.recvfrom()` is a pair like:

```
0xpublic?kC0^0+>Linux manager 3.4.30 #1 SMP Wed Sep 3 11:31:42 UTC 2014 x86_64+C?R?
('1.2.3.4', 161)
```

which is the SNMP message I'm getting back from the server, and the server IP I'm communicating with. The idea is to append the SNMP MIB into that string.

Comment: The size of the data has to match your format specifier. It doesn't. I am not sure how exactly we can help here.

Comment: Could you expand on how the structure of `self.recvfrom(self.DATA_SIZE)` would be expected to look like and how you would like `struct.unpact` to modify it before appending to data` ?

Comment: @user3197452 I will post a sample ...

Comment: is self.DATA_SIZE 43? If you are trying to read data at the front of a larger blob of data, use `unpack_from`.

Comment: @tdelaney I've modified my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your code expects that all received data will decode using "!2B I 4H 24s I B". Considering the `if not current_data` right after the log message, this isn't necessarily the case. If decode is only valid for some incoming data, you could wrap the log output in an try/except block and continue processing.

Comment: @tdelaney makes sense. could you translate it to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reading datagrams up to 2048 bytes in length and then decoding the first 43 bytes to log smtp information. The problem is that the datagram may be more or less than 43 bytes. I think you can solve your problem by using `unpack_from` to decode the first part of the message and simply reject messages that are too small. Precompiling the struct saves a bit of time, so I'm doing that too.

```
class Whatever(object):

    DATA_SIZE = 2048
    snmp_header = struct.Struct("!2B I 4H 24s I B")

    def handle_read(self):
            """
            This handles the incoming snmp response
            """
            try:
                data = ""
                while 1:
                    current_data, _ = self.recvfrom(self.DATA_SIZE)
                    self.log.info("msg: %s" % current_data)
                    if len(current_data) >= self.snmp_header.size:
                        (header, length, typeID, param1, param2,
                        param3, param4, name_string, checksum, footer,
                        ) = self.snmp_header.unpack_from("!2B I 4H 24s I B", current_data)
                        print  (header, length, typeID, param1, param2,
                        param3, param4, name_string, checksum, footer,
                        )
                    else:
                        print("received datagram too small")
                    if not current_data:
                        break
                    data += current_data
                self.log.info(data)
                # parse with the pysnmp into a summary
            except Exception, e:
                self.log.exception("The following exception happened: %s" % e)
            finally:
                self.handle_close()
```